# g.getOutputs is not a function while Creating a Chart from a Series

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, time-series

I created a Time Series of NDVI from Sentinel 2 Data, now I want to Chart it, using the following code. I get the error

> g.getOutputs is not a function

I never used g.getOutputs, and from what I read, it seems to be an error on the GEE side.

```js
 var sentinel2Collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
 .filterDate('2000-01-01','2017-12-31')
 .filterBounds(aoi);

 print(sentinel2Collection);

Map.centerObject(aoi, 10)

var imageS2 = sentinel2Collection.select(['B8', 'B4']).mosaic();

var addNDVI = function(im){
    var ndvi = im.select(['B8','B4']).normalizedDifference();
    return ndvi;
};

var ndviCollectionS2 = sentinel2Collection.filterBounds(aoi).map(addNDVI);
print(ndviCollectionS2.first()); 
Map.addLayer(ndviCollectionS2,  { min: -0.8, max: 0.8,'palette': 'FF0000,FFFF00,00FF00'},' NDVISentinel2');
print(ndviCollectionS2)
ui.Chart.image.series(ndviCollectionS2, /*'Sentinel2NDVi',*/ aoi, 'median');
```

[Code to GEE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3f8b54a23c014ef555acbf9ea0970c84)

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to `print` the chart to be displayed.

2) The reducer expects an reducer object, instead of a string i.e. `ee.Reducer.median()`

3) The series chart requires the acquisition time property. You can keep this if you simply add the NDVI as a band instead of creating a new image with just the NDVI.

```js
var sentinel2Collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
 .filterDate('2000-01-01','2017-12-31')
 .filterBounds(aoi);

 print(sentinel2Collection);

Map.centerObject(aoi, 10)

 var imageS2 = sentinel2Collection.select(['B8', 'B4']).mosaic();

var addNDVI = function(im){

var ndvi = im.select(['B8','B4']).normalizedDifference();
return im.addBands(ndvi);

};

var ndviCollectionS2 = sentinel2Collection.map(addNDVI);
print(ndviCollectionS2.first()); 
Map.addLayer(ndviCollectionS2.select("nd"),  { min: -0.8, max: 0.8,'palette': 'FF0000,FFFF00,00FF00'},' NDVISentinel2');
print(ndviCollectionS2)
print(ui.Chart.image.series(ndviCollectionS2.select("nd"), /*'Sentinel2NDVi',*/ aoi, ee.Reducer.median()));
```